# AdMob: AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL

Tags: android, admob

I read a lot of previous AdMob posts, but none sufficiently answer the question about the AdLoader timeout problem.  This is the error: http://i42.tinypic.com/9s5ag4.jpg

Note: I am using older jar file (**GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar**) because I am targeting an older Android version.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.something.www"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AdActivityActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" >
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

**AdActivity.java**

```
package com.something.www;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.ads.*;
public class AdActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        layout.addView(adView);
        AdRequest ar = new AdRequest();
        ar.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        ar.addTestDevice("425EF274CEBECB11F9EFEBF5B51458B1");
        adView.loadAd(ar);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine - this is likely just a network error?  Can you reach the internet on a web browser on the emulator/device?

FYI, you can still target old Android versions with the latest AdMob SDK (currently 4.3.1).  Check out [this blog post](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/migrating-to-v431-of-admob-sdk-for.html) for details on how to migrate to 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error (AdLoader timed out after 60000ms while getting the URL), but only in release builds. The error was shown in under 1 second, so it might be a different issue than the one you are having. Disabling proguard optimizations by adding the following to my proguard.cfg solved the problem:

```
-dontoptimize
# Also comment out the existing line controlling optimizations:
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
```